# Getting video info from storage is not working

Tags: java, android, video

I'm trying to get video width and size using this simple code:

```
String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATA,
                        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.WIDTH,
                        MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.HEIGHT};
cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(mVideoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      mVideoDecodableString = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]));
      mVideoWidth = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[1]));
      mVideoHeight = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[2]));
}
```

Unfortunatelly I always get 0 width and height for every video file in my gallery, but getting video data works.

Am I doing something wrong, or it's not possible in Android?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `MediaMetadataRetriever` to retrieve height & width of video file.

You need to use the `extractMetadata()` method using `METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT` and `METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH` constants like below.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metaRetriever.setDataSource(/* file path goes here. eg."/path/to/video.mp4" */);
String height = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
String width = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
```

**Note:** `MediaMetadataRetriever` require **API level 10** or above.

**Edit:**

I am not sure but, I think you need to use [RESOLUTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.html#RESOLUTION) column to get resolution(width × height) of video file form `ContentResolver` like below example.

```
String[] projection = new String[] {MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.RESOLUTION};
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    String resolution = cursor.getString(0);
    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(resolution)) {
        int index = resolution.indexOf('x');
        width = Integer.parseInt(resolution.substring(0, index));
        height = Integer.parseInt(resolution.substring(index + 1));
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, my question is why code in the question doesn't work? If you can explain, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @ThirdMartian check my edited answer for getting video resolution form  `ContentResolver`.